# How to make an ascending list in Racket?

Tags: list, merge, scheme, racket

I merge two lists into one in Racket. Here the code:

```
(define (merge-tail l1 l2) 
  (cond 
    [(empty? l1) l2] 
    [(empty? l2) l1] 
    [(cons (car l1) (merge-tail l2 (cdr l1)))]))
```

The result is correct. For example `'(15 8 42) '(24 54 7) --> '(15 24 8 54 42 7).`

I want to make the result in ascending order. How can I do that?

Comment: Use `(sort (merge-tail l1 l2) <)`?

Comment: It works though now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: surely that's not what's expected here. what's the point in defining / using `merge-tail` at all now, if all you need is the built-in `append`. The definition should probably be tweaked so that with the new function the call `(merge-ascending (sort l1 <) (sort l2 <))` will work. (cc @Shawn)

Comment: (@Will Ness) I get your explanation. But merge-tail is the code that the instructor provide and expected to go with.

Comment: to use it, or to change it, is the question. :)

Comment: @Will Ness Sorry about the confusion.